# stop postfix relay from internal network

Tags: postfix

I'm using Postfix 2.7.1 (can't change to a newer version for the moment) and it's running fine, with the exception that is allowing to relay mail from the internal network even if the specified sender is not from the domain served by Postfix.

In other words, if my domain is mydomain.com, any computer on my local network is allowed to send emails to any other domain using bogusaccount@anotherdomain.com as the sender's email address, how can I stop this?

I have this in main.cf:

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination

I've tried to restrict mynetworks to only localhost or change the order in smtpd_recipient_restrictions to this:

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated

but the result is that none of the users on the network can send emails.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What shows up in your logs when you restrict mynetworks to just localhost and internal users send email?

Comment: I got 'relay access denied'

Comment: Which is correct, what you may want to do is look at http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps sender login maps, where you create a file that maps sasl logins to authorized senders.  Users will have to use sasl authorization to send though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issues with people sending with "unofficial" or bogus accounts, the [smtpd_sender_login_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) option is what you need. It will take the SASL login name, and check the file/DB/regex to see if the From: name is valid, and either relay, or deny. You will have to create the mappings, but that's the only work involved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to send emails out, as long as they are from your domain as the sender address.

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unlisted_sender, check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/localdomain, reject
```

/etc/postfix/localdomain :

```
mydomain.com      OK
```

In localdomain you can also add any compromised accounts which come up:

```
passwdguessed@mydomain.com    550 Account compromised
```

Don't forget to run postmap on localdomain file since it is a hashed file reference.

Comment: this solution actually does NOT work, as it prevents to receive any emails from the outside, even if the recipient is a valid user.

Comment: I recommend running a second postfix for SMTP and using this type of control.  That is, a dedicated postfix instance for MX, and another for SMTP.  It provides more granular control, and if the above solution is applied on the SMTP instance, it works well to deal with compromised accounts.